# Unable to pass the value of function on button click in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to pass the value into function on button click . but when I am doing that I am getting the value as "Undefined"

please tell me a solution to pass the value into the function

> .ts file

```js
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {}

    togg(string name) {
        console.log(name);
        this.dropdowns[name] = !this.dropdowns[name];
    }
 }
```

> .html file

```html
<button (click)="togg('toggle_menu3');"> click </button>
```

Comment: Do you get an undefined when logging `name` or `this.dropdowns[name]`?

Comment: ` togg(string name) ` this is not how you delcare parameters in TS

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-em8xnv

Changed togg to be properly written like

```
togg(name: string) {
  console.log(name);
  // rest of code
}
```

and changed html to remove the semi colon (not actually needed)

```
<button (click)="togg('toggle_menu3')">test<button>
```

Comment: Presence of the semi-column isn't annoying. However it becomes necessary when using several functions.

Comment: Oh I agree. I was just noting my changes.